# Abstract Algebra: Every group has a cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I have to show that every group has a cyclic subgroup. I know what this means, and to me it is obvious, yet I am not sure how to formally write it.

I proved it directly, as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group.
>
> Let $g$ be an element in $G$.
>
> Let $o(g) = k$, i.e., $g^k = e$, for some integer $k$,
>
> so by definition, $\langle g\rangle = \{e, g, g^2, \dots, g^{k-1}\}$,
>
> therefore, for some $g\in G$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$ is in fact a subgroup of $G$.

Would that be sufficient to prove the statement? Did I leave anything out, or should I mention anything else?

New version of the proof:

> Let $G$ be a finite group.
>
> If $G = \{e\}$, then $G = \langle e\rangle$, i.e., cyclic.
>
> If $G\neq\{e\}$, then there exists $g\neq e$, for $g\in G$.
>
> Let $m$ be minimum positive integer s.t. $g^m = e$.
>
> Then $g, g^2, \dots, g^m = e$ are distinct elements in $G$ generated by $g$
>
> So $e, g, g^2, \dots, g^{m-1}$ form a cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ in $G$.

Comment: why such $k$ would exist?? Take $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition

Comment: Is that exactly how the question is stated?

Comment: @ drawnonward yes, the question is "Show that every group has a cyclic subgroup"

Comment: Trivially, I believe the identity element always serves as a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: What definition of cyclic group are you using?

Comment: I agree, yet I do not think it is enough to show it holds for just the identity element

Comment: @Rupert "A group generated by a single element is called a cyclic group
{g, $g^2$, $g^3$, . . . , $g^{k−1}$, $g^k$ = e}" is the definition I was given

Comment: All right. So a group is cyclic if it has a generating set consisting of just one element. Let's say we want to prove that every group with more than one element has a cyclic subgroup with more than one element. Take a nonidentity element of the group and consider the subgroup generated by that element. This is a cyclic subgroup.

Comment: It's important to realise that some cyclic groups are infinite. The group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition is an example.

Comment: this might be cheating, but couldn't you say that every group contains a neutral element, which can be used to form the trivial group, which is cyclic? ps. just saw that @drawnonward already mentioned this.

Comment: @kritzikratzi , I don't think it is cheating, because in some groups, it will be the only proper cyclic subgroup....for example $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$  I think the purpose here is to assume the group has finite cardinality = n, then n=pm, p prime and by lagranges theorem we are done.

Comment: @drawnonward The trivial subgroup is the only proper cyclic subgroup only if the original group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$ for some prime $p$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect. You take an element $g\in G$ and immediatelly claim that $o(g) = k$ for some integer $k$. However, you cannot claim that, as there are groups in which no element has finite order.

Comment: Should I first prove that the cyclic subgroup has order o(_g_)?

Comment: @Njal **Hint** $\mathbb Z$ is also a cyclic group.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what to do, going to edit the post

Answer (score 4):

As already said, it is not true that an arbitrary group has always a finite cyclic subgroup: take $\Bbb Z$ under addition.

However, what is true, is that an arbitrary group $G$ has always a cyclic subgroup. Take an element $g\in G$ and consider the subgroup of $G$ generated by this element: $\langle g\rangle$.

You have now two cases:

1)$\operatorname{ord}(g)$ is finite, say $N$; then
$$
\langle g\rangle=\{1_G,g,g^2,\dots,g^{N-1}\}=\{g^k\;:\;0\le k\le N-1\}
$$

for example you can take $G=S_n$ the symmetric group and $g=(1,2,\dots,n)$, or even $G=\Bbb Z_n$ the class of remainder modulo $n$, which is a group under addition, and take $g=1$. An interesting example is the one given by the group $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ which is an infinite group taking a idempotent matrix as $g$.

2)$\operatorname{ord}(g)=\infty$: the situation is as above, except the fact that the list of elements in $\langle g\rangle$ never ends, i.e.
$$
\langle g\rangle=\{1_G,g,g^2,\dots,g^{k},\dots\}=\{g^k\;:\;k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}\}
$$
for example take $G=\Bbb Z$ with $g=1$ or even $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ as above with a non idempotent matrix as $g$.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Every group has a finite cyclic subgroup $\{1\}$.